# How can I prevent submission of a Foundry form if one field has a greater value than another?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I’ve setup a Foundry Form with two numeric fields (let’s call them `Num A` and `Num B`). I’m trying to add a constraint such that the form cannot be submitted if `Num A < Num B`.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by doing the following:

1. Define a new `Calculation` field that stores the result of subtracting `Num B` from `Num A`. The configuration for this field should look something like the screenshot below:
   [image: Defining Calculation Field]
2. Add a validator to the `Calculation` field such that its value cannot be negative (in other words, it must have a minimum value of 0). Configuration for this validator should look like the following:
   [image: Calculation validation form]

If these steps are followed, the form will block submission if `Num A < Num B` as shown in the screenshot below.
[image: Input box showing validation working]